# objects are keep falling

Tags: unity, c#, physics

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I added some screenshots above. When I run the game obstacle are falling rapidly through `y` axis. So, there's no more obstacle in that ground. If there's ground than those obstacle should stopped. I tried by freezing them. But, when another object hit them they are froze. So, I want ground to stop them. I have another question also. I have player movement. When I will run the program. The `Player` should be go through `z` axis. But, The object(player) don't move.

PlayerMovement.cs

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rb; 
    public float forwardForce=2000f;
    

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.AddForce(0,0,forwardForce * Time.deltaTime);
        if(Input.GetKey("d")){
            rb.AddForce(30 * Time.deltaTime,0,0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }else if(Input.GetKey("a")){
            rb.AddForce(-30 * Time.deltaTime,0,0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);   
        }
           
        if(!Input.touchSupported)
        {
            // Still support PC keys
            if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
            {
                rb.AddForce(30 * Time.deltaTime,0,0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
            }
            else if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
            {
                rb.AddForce(-30 * Time.deltaTime,0,0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);   
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // For touch devices
            if(Input.touchCount == 1)
            {
                var touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
                var touchPos = touch.position;
            
                var isRight = touchPos.x >= Screen.width / 2f;
            
                if(isRight)
                {
                    rb.AddForce(30 * Time.deltaTime,0,0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
                }
                else
                {
                    rb.AddForce(-30 * Time.deltaTime,0,0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);   
                }
            }
        }




        if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position,Vector3.down,0.5f)==false){
            // rb.velocity = new Vector3(0, rb.velocity.y, 0);
            rb.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePositionZ;
        }else{
            rb.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.None;
        }

        if(rb.position.y < -1f){
            FindObjectOfType<GameManager>().EndGame();
        }
    }
}
```

PlayerCollision.cs

```cs
﻿using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class PlayerCollision : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    public PlayerMovement movement;

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collisionInfo)
    {
        Debug.Log(collisionInfo.collider.name);
        if (collisionInfo.collider.tag == "obstacle")
        {
            movement.enabled = false;
            FindObjectOfType<GameManager>().EndGame();
        }else if(collisionInfo.collider.name == "END"){
            FindObjectOfType<GameManager>().CompleteLevel();
        }
    }
    void Restart(){
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
    }
}
```

[image]

If you look at above source code clearly. So, you might see that I have a `Debug.Log` right there. But, when I run the game. I don't get any message to console.

As a new game developer(learning) I don't know what's happening, what's wrong with this.

Comment: This looks like you're still solving the same problem as [your previous question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/189123/39518). Instead of posting a new question, please edit the existing question to focus on the problem as you now understand it thanks to your troubleshooting. Be sure to show us your physics layer settings. Do not pack two questions into one post.

Comment: @DMGregory OK! I understood why you closed it..... :)